# Free Windows Subversion GUI that does NOT use a shell extension

Tags: svn

I need a Subversion user interface that meets the following requirements:

- User interface that runs on Windows
- Does NOT require usage of a shell extension (if one is included, it should be optional)
- Actively maintained (i.e. new, regular releases within the past year)
- Free

Surprisingly, I'm having trouble finding such a thing!  I want it for working with the occasional Subversion repository - I won't be using it on a daily basis.  For that reason, options like TortoiseSVN are NOT really desired because they will clutter up and slow down my Windows Explorer shell.  (I already have shell extensions for Git and seemingly a million other apps, the last thing I need is yet another shell extension for a source control package I'm going to only rarely use.)

A comparable project for Git is [Git Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/).  Binaries are provided for Windows, it's GPL, the last release was within the past 30 days, and the shell extension is optional: it's a standalone GUI.  I'm surprised I haven't found such a thing for SVN...

Comment: Did you go through this list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Subversion_clients ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: yes I did. :)

Comment: Have you tried TortoiseSVN with the Icon Overlays turned off?  That improves performance, as does being judicious about including/excluding paths from the icon overlay.

Comment: Also, I expect that the shell extension could be unregistered, and you could just launch tortoise when you needed it.

Comment: @Chris: I thought TortoiseSVN was 100% a shell extension and can't be used without Windows Explorer / shell?

Comment: TortoiseSVN has an option to display status icons overlays in Windows Explorer. This should fix all slowness that you notice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Subversion WorkBench](https://scm-workbench.barrys-emacs.org/) may be a good solution satisfying your requirements. And it's free of course!

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that most Windows users love TortoiseSVN so much that there isn't much demand for other Windows clients. However, there are a few:

- [RapidSVN](https://rapidsvn.org/). This is one of the Tigris projects that CollabNet has (and Subversion was also a Tigris project). It's official version is 0.12 which seems to me to say that the developers don't have much faith in the product.
- [QSvn](https://anrichter.github.io/qsvn/). From a KDE project for a Subversion client using the QT toolkit. It should work on Windows, but like many QT projects, it'll probably have a decidedly non-Windows feel to it.
- [PySvn](https://pysvn.sourceforge.io/): now has the GUI part of it under a separate name as [SCM Workbench](https://scm-workbench.barrys-emacs.org/) leaving PySVN just for the SVN command line library. You don't need to install Python beforehand any more.

Word 'o Warning: I never used any of these tools. I like using the command line client myself.

Comment: +1 for your comment on TortoiseSVN. And there is a reason why lots of people like an SVN client to be a shell extension. If one does not like it, one can configure the shell integration to the very minimum of menu entries.

Comment: The issue isn't about the number of menu entries TortoiseSVN adds; the issue is that TortoiseSVN is being loaded into memory in the first place.  That makes my computer boot slower, general folder browsing slower, etc. etc.  Every time I right-click something, TortoiseSVN code is being called and has to remain in RAM.  Even if it's a small amount, it still makes a difference.  Not worth it for the occasional use I'm doing.

Comment: @DocBrown There's a lot of convenience in the Tortoise integration, and the integration is familiar with users. You don't have to _learn_ something new. You browse and commit in the same window. However, there is a significant performance penalty, so I understand people who want to avoid it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [SmartSVN](https://www.smartsvn.com/) from Syntevo.

Comment: I use SmartSVN at home. It's originally packed with some premium features, that you can only use before the trial expires, and then you are stuck with the basic, standard features of the free version. However, I don't know what they are since SmartSVN still has everything I need

Comment: you can not even tag or branch when the trial expires.